# Stretch background div to 100% vertical even when content is overflowing

Tags: css, jquery-ui, html

I know I'm missing something basic, I've jumped through the better part of 2 dozen posts to try to figure out what I'm looking for...but can't seem to get it right.  Take a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ttGgH/

I have a div that I need to stretch vertically, which is perfect on page load.  the second I get data overrun that needs scrolling, the div no longer fixes, it stops at 100% of the original window.  What am I missing to make it hit 100% vertical regardless of how much data is in the container?  I know there's probably something that covers this, apologies.  I couldnt find it!

CSS:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background:#333;
    margin:0;
}

.container_fullscreen {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background:#ccc;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.BRC_main_wrapper {
    height:100%;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.BRC_main_sidenav {
    width:120px;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    float:left;
}

.BRC_grid_4columns {
    min-width:275px;
    width:100%;
    max-width:357px;
    float:left;
}

.BRC_grid_activegutter {
    margin:8px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<body>
<div class="container_fullscreen">
    <div class="BRC_main_wrapper">
        <div class="BRC_main_sidenav"></div>
        <!--- grid --->
        BLA BLA BLA<br>
        BLA BLA BLA<br>
        BLA BLA BLA<br>
        <!--- end grid --->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

[image: HERES A PICTURE TO DESCRIBE WHAT IM LOOKING FOR]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ttGgH/1/ Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: not quite, because of the overflow scroll.  It throws another scrollbar in there, I just want it to scroll natively as a page.

Comment: Not clear what you want.  Can you mock something up that shows how it should look?

Comment: Could explain what do you want?

Comment: Here's a screen shot to describe it better.... http://seprockies.org/bgscroll.png

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all your absolute positioning on that container and use:

```
 overflow:auto
```

And add to your body:

```
margin: 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ttGgH/2/

Comment: Hi Rob -That unfortunately doesn't work. if you make your window cell large enough it doesn't go 100% height....

Comment: You want the entire background to be grey, right? not black? This page is completely grey bg, no matter how much content you put in it. Check  this link: http://jsfiddle.net/ttGgH/3/

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
min-height: 100%;
```

Funny thing, my message is too short, but it is as simple as that.

Comment: no, that doesnt work unfortunately, I've already attempted that...and it also has compatibility issues.